# how to configure the Penthao 8.2 bulk insert with snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pentaho-data-integration

how to configure the Penthao 8.2 PDI bulk insert with snowflake?

Or is there any plug in available to bulk insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend upgrading to Pentaho 8.3, as they have released a lot of new capabilities with their connection to Snowflake.  Read here:
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.3/What%27s_new_in_Pentaho_8.3

More details about bulk loading features here:
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.3/Products/Bulk_load_into_Snowflake#GUID-C28ACDBB-F9B7-4866-BF52-C29A0415BA56